# Is it possible to hide busy indicator in smart table?

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table with action buttons in it. When I click on action button, whole smart table is covered with busy indicator, until data for action button is retrieved from back end. I tried to hide busy indicator on smart table with *

> setBusy(false)

and

> sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide()

however it somehow does not work.

My question is, is it not possible to hide busy indicator on smart table? Is it UI5 by default property for smart table?

Comment: I think this is default behavior. Maybe you can make a custom control extending smarttable and overriding the busy state management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't ask why you don't want the busy indicator to be shown. Assuming you are using XML views you should be able to use attribute `busyIndicatorDelay` and apply a very high value to delay the displaying of the busy indicator. For further details check the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#setBusyIndicatorDelay).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be a custom CSS rule for setting the busy indicator's display style to `none`.

Let's say you did set an ID `tableId` for your Smart Table, the CSS rule would be

```
[id$=tableId] .sapUiLocalBusyIndicator {
    display: none;
}
```

To apply the rule on all of your Smart Tables use

```
.sapUiCompSmartTable .sapUiLocalBusyIndicator` {
    display: none;
}
```

In case you only want to hide the busy indicator if you click on a specific action button you could use the method **addStyleClass** with a custom class in your action handler and specify the CSS rule accordingly.
Of course you have to remove the class after the data is received.

Comment: It seems easy solution, however, According to best practices, we are not allowed to add custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue when I had set the `SmartTable`'s `enableAutoBinding` property to `true` since I wanted to populate the table data when the app initially launches.

To resolve the issue, if you have added a Table within `SmartTable` in your view, set an ID to it e.g. "idTable" and add the following line in the view's `onInit` method:

> this.byId("idTable").setBusy(false);

If you have not added a Table within `SmartTable` in your view, fetch the `SmartTable` instance and use the API `getTable()` to fetch the contained table, and then use the above method in `onInit`